# Unable to list nuget artifacts after upgraded to 6.8.7

Tags: artifactory

Upgraded `Artifactory` from `5.5.x` to `6.8.7`
Now `nuget` artifact download isn't working
no errors on `artifactory.log`

```
PM> ./nuget install Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events -verbosity detailed
NuGet Version: 4.9.4.5839
Feeds used:
  http://qa-repo.mitchell.com/artifactory/api/nuget/test-sk/

Installing package 'Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events' to 'C:\Users\sk101574\Downloads'.
  GET http://qa-repo.mitchell.com/artifactory/api/nuget/test-sk/FindPackagesById()?id='Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events'&semVerLevel=2.0.0
  OK http://qa-repo.mitchell.com/artifactory/api/nuget/test-sk/FindPackagesById()?id='Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 20ms
./nuget : Unable to find package 'Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events'
At line:1 char:1
+ ./nuget install Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events -verbosity det ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to find ...eration.Events':String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

NuGet.CommandLine.CommandLineException: Unable to find package 'Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events'
   at NuGet.CommandLine.InstallCommand.<InstallPackageAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
```

Comment: when I hit the URL http://qa-repo.mitchell.com/artifactory/api/nuget/test-sk/FindPackagesById()?id='Mitchell.CSG.ArtifactGeneration.Events'&semVerLevel=2.0.0 on browser it works

Comment: https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-is-my-nuget-client-failing-to-download-packages/ this should help us for logs and you for debugging